# Is it OK to use UCC API in 2017?

Tags: sip, uccapi

I'm looking for a SIP/RTP implementation for C#, and I've stumbled upon MS "[UCC API SDK](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/lync/2008/05/13/ucc-api-what-is-it-and-how-does-one-write-an-application-using-it/)", which looks promising at first glance. But googling it gives information mostly related to Lync, and dated around 2007-2008.

Is this technology alive? Should I try it or just let it rest in peace?

Also, is there a better (preferably open-source) solution for SIP/RTP client for .Net?

Answer (score 0):

take into consideration that in 2017 some of the major codecs were developed in the late 90s.
for a softphone sip/rtp g711 codec will be around for many more years to come.

The telephony sector is one of if not the slowest technology moving forward.
we may be getting webrtc and all fancy unicorns. yet the fundamental base core is still the same old.